# Integrating IBM Connections with Oracle Issue

Tags: ibm-connections

I am having IBM connections setup in Windows system whereas i am having Oracle installed on another AIX system where i am facing issues connecting with database. Can anyone help me through this?

```
How to specify the database location of remote system? Can I have any link for installation guide IBM Connections 4.5?
```

Answer (score 2):

These 2 links would help in configuring a remote database:

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/lcwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+Connections+4.5+Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Creating_Oracle_databases_manually_ic45&content=pdcontent

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/lcwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+Connections+4.5+documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Installing_IBM_Connections_4.5_ic45&content=pdcontent

Comment: I would also point to IBM Connections Wizard, you can use it in console mode.  also Connections.sql in the installation folder contains the scripts for Oracle and db2.